# Format input in kable table R

Tags: r, kable

This is my reproduceable code:

```
library(splines)
var = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
degree.freedom <- c(4,5,6)

list1 <- list()
list2 <- list()
for (i in 1:length(degree.freedom)){
  attr <- attr(bs(var, df=degree.freedom[i]) ,"knots")
  list1[[i]] <- names(attr)
  list2[[i]] <- unname(attr)
}
knitr::kable(cbind(list1,list2), col.names=c("list1","list2"))
```

WHere I obtain the following table:

[image]

But I would like to obtain a more pretty table as:

[image]

what can I do to `list1` and `list2` to obtain the desired table?

NB:
I made the desired table using:

```
list1 <- c("[50%]","[33.33%, 66.67%]","[25%, 50%, 75%]")
list2 <- c("[5.0]","[4.0, 7.0]","[3.25, 5.50, 7.75]")
```

Comment: You could try something like: `cbind(paste0('[', lapply(list1, paste, collapse = ', '), ']'), paste0('[', lapply(list2, paste, collapse = ', '), ']'))`

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind writing an answer, so I can mark the question as answered? And in addition would it be possible to round the percentages to two decimals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list, such as `list1`:

```
[[1]]
[1] "50%"

[[2]]
[1] "33.33333333333332859638%" "66.66666666666665719276%"

[[3]]
[1] "25%" "50%" "75%"
```

You can convert to comma-separated values, enclosed in brackets by:

```
paste0('[', lapply(list1, paste, collapse = ', '), ']')

[1] "[50%]"                                                "[33.33333333333332859638%, 66.66666666666665719276%]"
[3] "[25%, 50%, 75%]"
```

In this case, `lapply` will use `paste` together each element, and `collapse` will insert commas between values.

Since you are using `bs` from `splines`, it generates percentages which are character values. The number of digits is dependent on your settings. For me:

```
getOption("digits")
[1] 22
```

(Note that the random digits towards the end are noise...)

You can specify the number of digits printed (not decimal places) by setting:

```
options(digits = 4)
```

Which would give you:

```
|list1            |list2             |
|:----------------|:-----------------|
|[50%]            |[5.5]             |
|[33.33%, 66.67%] |[4, 7]            |
|[25%, 50%, 75%]  |[3.25, 5.5, 7.75] |
```

Also note: `kable` allows for `digits` to be set; however, this applies to numeric values. The character values would not be affected.